# LightGBMError: Do not support non-ascii characters in feature name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lightgbm

Всегда работал с lightGBM бустингом. Недавно переустановил питон, и lightGBM перестал работать с именами предикторов на кириллице, выводя ошибку в заголовке. Что-то забыл доустановить?

Comment: Посмотрите на [эту проблему](https://github.com/awslabs/autogluon/issues/399) и на [этот запрос функции](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2478). Надеюсь, это поможет тебе.